# ASP loading assembly(dll) error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, dll

I have an ASP application and I am using the functionality of exporting to Word ( from my `RadEditor`).

Now I have the following dll and I have placed it in the right folder from where the system should reference it and I want my system to reference only this version of dll :-

```
Telerik.Windows.Documents.Core.dll  
Version 2016.3.1021.40
```

But whenever I am doing exporting to word it is throwing the below error :-

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Windows.Documents.Core, Version=2015.3.930.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Now can anyone please advise why my system is pointing to `Version=2015.3.930.45` when I have `Version 2016.3.1021.40`, and I did not keep any other version of that dll except the `Version 2016....` anywhere in my entire project  or  what can be done in this situation . ThankYou !

Comment: Is there a reference to that other version in the config file?

Comment: @jmcilhinney , no there is no reference to any of the above versions in the  config file !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try any of the following:

1. The reference in the config file entry is still pointing to old version. Try to remove the dll and clear the entry in config and re-add
2. Sometimes cleaning the solution and re-building should simply fix this. (you can try cleaning bin and obj folders manually before doing this)
3. Remove Temporary Files C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
4. Or any other Telerik DLL which has dependency on this is still using the older version. Try to update all the DLLs related to Telerik Or try to use the DLLs of same versions

Comment: Ok. Did you already try all the other ways mentioned above? Or any other ways which you have idea of?

Comment: Cannot see the error message - can you pls add it to your comment?

Comment: I suspect, one of your other Telerik DLLs is trying to refer to old version or core.dll which you had earlier. Why don't you update all the references to newer version and try re-building? Or all the temp files are not completely cleaned up.